# Using arrays to loop through starting multiple threads, pass different parameters, and return handles for WaitForMultipleObjects

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I want to test out using WaitForMultipleObjects, and to do so I want to start multiple threads, using a loop, each passing different ThreadArgs.

(Essentially just an array of five ThreadArgs, and five HANDLEs?)

When I try to create an array of either the struct, or the HANDLE, neither will work and I get the error 'cannot allocate an array of constant size 0' for both, and ''initializing' : cannot convert from 'HANDLE' to 'HANDLE []'' for the latter.

Is an array the appropriate way to do this with regards to the struct? (Also, a note - it will have to remain a struct as it will contain six members eventually, I'm just trying to get it working in a simpler form at first, since adding these members should be very straightforward)

And I'd assume an array of Handles is the best way to do this, but how do I go about declaring one?

Thank you!

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <process.h>


struct ThreadArgs 
{
    int id;
};

ThreadArgs args = {1}; 


unsigned int __stdcall MyThread(void *data)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    ThreadArgs *args = (ThreadArgs *) data; 

    std::cout << (*args).id;

    return 2;
}

int main()
{

    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, MyThread, &args, 0, NULL); 

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);


    while(true);

}
```

The above is my code currently.

I was trying to create an array of HANDLEs using -

```
HANDLE hThread[5];
```

**Edit:**

The error is on this line, when it is altered to be an array of HANDLE[5] -

```
HANDLE hThread[0] = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, MyThread, &args, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Where is the error in your code?

Comment: Ah, sorry - there is no error in the current code - it is working; however when I try to create an array of HANDLE hThread[5]; (which will mean HANDLE hThread = becomes HANDLE hThread[0] and WaitForSingleObect(hThread, INFINITE) becomes WaitForSingleObject(hThread[0], INFINITE)...

Comment: ... the error is on this line - 
HANDLE hThread[0] = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, MyThread, &args, 0, NULL);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and pass it an array of handles to wait for multiple threads to complete. See an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) here.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

CRITICAL_SECTION cs;

struct ThreadArgs 
{
    int id;
};

VOID MyThread(void *data)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    ThreadArgs *args = (ThreadArgs*)data;
    cout << args->id << endl;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
}

int main()
{
    InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);

    vector <HANDLE> T;

    DWORD id;

    ThreadArgs args[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        T.push_back(CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MyThread, &args[i], 0, &id));
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(5, &T[0], TRUE, INFINITE);

    DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks - I'll try to figure out the handles from that example. 

What about creating the struct? I get 'cannot allocate an array of constant size 0' when I try to create an array of the struct.

Comment: Can you post your code on how are you creating an array of struct?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the example? I don't see where two threads are being started? And why are there two types of handles? Sorry.

Comment: As for the struct - 

Test test[2]; 

That will create it with no errors, but as soon as I try to access it's members, I get a string of errors.

Comment: @ShimmerGeek: As I'm guessing, you need to initialize your arrays inside a function not in global scope, or do it `Test test[2] = {1, 2};`.

Comment: Thanks. (This is driving me crazy, I keep making such obvious, big mistakes)

Comment: @ShimmerGeek: Also, since you're working in C++, you could use a `std::vector` instead of creating an array of thread handles.

Comment: I really don't understand the example at all :/